# Treating MySQL's BIT datatype on different OS

Tags: php, mysql, linux, windows, type-conversion

I had no problems working with MySQL's BIT data type on a Windows environment with PHP and PDO. The only trick that I used was to cast it to int.

But when I uploaded the code to a Linux server, then I wasn't able to see those BIT values: I was getting a square character.

After searching for this, I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2916932/702353) by Marc B, which coupled with Stanimir Stoyanov's comment I ended up doing this for both Windows and Linux and it's working great

**CODE FOR DISPLAY**

```
//linux OR windows
$display = ($value_from_db === chr(0x01) || $value_from_db == 1) ? 1 : 0;
```

**CODE FOR SAVING**

```
//both platforms
$value_for_db = ($display == 1) ? 0x01 : 0x00;
```

So my questions are:

- Are both platforms indeed treating this data type differently?
- Or is it a specific programm issue? (php, apache, mysql)
- Is this the correct way to address this issue? Maybe there's another
  approach

Windows 7: PHP 5.6.10, Apache 2.4.12, MySQL 5.6.26

Debian Wheezy: PHP 5.5.30, Apache 2.2.22, MySQL 5.6.25

Comment: try this `INSERT INTO tab1 (bit_field) values (b?)`, you can bind boolean or int value.

Comment: like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/36762564/5559741

Comment: You might want to include the code you're using to save and retrieve things from the database. PHP is very loosely typed, so just because you're setting something to an integer doesn't mean it's getting passed to the database that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the PHP functions `bindec` and `decbin`:

code for display

```
//linux OR windows
$display = bindec($value_from_db);
```

Code for saving

```
//both platforms
$value_for_db = decbin($display);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked very good on linux, on windows I'm only having problems with saving. I'm getting `22001 SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column`

Comment: Hi Matías, can you please provide the table structure to debug the problem? I mean the output for the ` SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name` SQL command.

Comment: I've upgraded PHP version, and everything seems to be working fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`BIT` is not a single bit, but it is a fixed-width bit-field value that ranges from 1 to 64. The value you store in a column of this datatype is stored as `BINARY`. Many client libraries, Command Line client and other GUI Clients do not know how to handle this value. It is also transmitted as BINARY value. How it is being displayed depends on the width of column. For example, if column is 32 bit wide, it is treated as `CHAR(4)` and in case of 8 bit wide, it is treated as `CHAR(1)`. That is why you need to cast it as an `INTEGER` value in order to display it properly.

In case of Microsoft SQL Server, BIT is a single-bit column and stored as a single bit within `INTEGER` datatype.

You can also try `BOOL` or `BOOLEAN` datatype for this. These datatypes are similar to `TINYINT(1)` which can store values other than 0 and 1. `TINYINT(1)` will consume full byte, but `BIT(1)` also does the same. According to this [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html), zero value is considered false and non-zero values are considered true. So, you assign it a value 2, it will be considered true. Therefore, if you want to allow only 0 and 1, then you should use `BIT` and cast the value to display it properly.

According to this [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-field-literals.html), one should cast BIT field to INT before displaying it. For this, with reference to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2916932/4932070), try following.

```
     $bitvalue = ($bitvalue == 0x01) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'
```

OR

```
     SELECT CAST(bitfield AS unsigned int)
```

Comment: using `bindec()` as Luigi suggested, resolved de display issue, right now I'm having trouble saving the value on windows (see my comment in Luigi's answer)

Comment: @Matías, I thought you had solved the problem, as you said, ` I ended up doing this for both Windows and Linux and it's working great`. If there is still a problem, you should refer to this page, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-field-literals.html

Comment: You should try `(bitfield AS unsigned)` in your query while saving data.

Comment: Yes, the problem is solved. But I'm trying to use a "universal" approach, instead of doing an OS based code

Comment: I am using the same configuration of windows and casting bit to int is working. Moreover, Miken32 has a point.